# Can you use multiple output layers in a neural network without using softmax?

Tags: classification, neural-network

I'm working on implementing a neural network for a class project and I was just wondering if it is possible to do multiclass classification with a neural network without using softmax? When I asked the TA about this he said that having multiple output layers isn't mathematically sound, but then I saw that Andrew Ng included a picture of a neural network with multiple outputs in his UFLDL tutorial on autoencoders, and then I see a lot of people talking about multiclass classification with neural networks without mentioning softmax. So I guess what I would like to know is whether it is appropriate to use multiple output layers without using softmax, and if so how would you do it and how would you interpret the results.

UFLDL link: http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/UFLDL_Tutorial

Answer (score 3):

Quite late, but perhaps someone will find it useful:

You don't have to use a softmax layer. You can, for instance, use multiple logistic regression layers or a single layer with multiple logistic regression outputs. The difference is that a softmax says with class is the most probable one, while multiple logistic regression outputs can assign a data point to several classes simultaneously.

Another approach is to use an arbitrary classifier(SVM, Random Forest, Boosting) on neural net output values (i.e. features).

I have recently forgot to put a softmax layer on top of a convolution neural network and I used a fully connected (inner product) layer as output with quite good results, too!

Answer (score 0):

Neural networks can also have multiple output units. For example, here is a network with two hidden layers layers L2 and L3 and two output units in layer L4:

[image: http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/images/Network3322.png]

You can see more details on this tutorial:
http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/MultiLayerNeuralNetworks/